VBA Script to import comma delimited .txt file into Excel - script stops running when there is no data in a field
I am trying to write a script that will import a comma-delimited text file into an Excel spreadsheet. My text file has some empty fields so the data might look like this: STRATFIELD ROAD,,FAIRFIELD, with the ",," indicating that the ADDRESS 2 field is empty.
I need my VBA to skip importing that field since it is empty. Right now the VBA script is stopping the import the instant it meets an empty field. I want it to import all data, leaving a cell empty if the field in the text file is blank.
Sub TestFileImport()

Dim fileToOpen As Variant
Dim fileFilterPattern As String
Dim wsMaster As Worksheet
Dim wbTextImport As Workbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

fileFilterPattern = "Text Files (*.txt), *.txt"

fileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(fileFilterPattern)

If fileToOpen = False Then
    ' Input cancelled
    MsgBox "No file selected."
Else
    ' file selected    

Workbooks.OpenText _
        Filename:=fileToOpen, _
        StartRow:=2, _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        Comma:=True
        
Set wbTextImport = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsMaster = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Data")

wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").CurrentRegion.Copy wsMaster.Range("A5")

wbTextImport.Close False

Worksheets("File Data").Columns.AutoFit

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End If

End Sub

I've tried a variety of different code I've found with Google but none of them continue the import past the empty fields.

How do you know that this is the stopping reason (empty field in the file)? ConsecutiveDelimiter default parameter is False, so it shouldn't be  bothered by this issue. If you choose a (testing) file without empty field, do you say that it can be open? Are there big numbers to be imported (with ThousandsSeparator as comma)?

Range.TextToColumns after importing the data to the sheet would typically perform the task.  I have typically done this after opening, e.g., Workbooks.Open("C:\Test.txt"), rather than using the delimiter tied to the open.

I don't that that's the reason, just that it stops at the 4th column which is typically blank in the txt file

Cyril where would I put that in the code?

You're using CurrentRegion to select the data for copy.  It's possible that's not selecting all the data.  Try commenting out wbTextImport.Close and see if all the data is there

@chris neilsen unfortunately that didn't help

Please explain what you see in wbTextImport

@chris you mean what does it look like in Excel when I try to run the script? It imports the first three fields into columns, then the rest of the columns are blank, even though there's data in the text file

When you comment out wbTextImport.Close you will be left with two open workbooks, your master wb and the newly created imported text wb.  Did you examine the new wb?

@chris "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range" and it imports everything into a new workbook

That's what I expected.   Change CurrentRegion to UsedRange and restore your wbTextImport.Close line.  Should be good to go then

@chris Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.
Is this correct?
wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).Range("A5").UsedRange.Copy wsMaster.Range("A5")

Not quite.   wbTextImport.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Copy

@chris Success! Thank you so much!

@vicoria good to hear. I sincerely hope you learned something along the way

Just follow the traditional way of sequentially reading of comma separated text file.
I think, you can understand how it is working.
Sub CSV_File2ExcelSheet()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim CSVName As String
Dim LineItems() As String
Dim rw As Long

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Set ws = Worksheets("File Data")
CSVName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Text Files (*.csv), *.csv")
If CSVName = "False" Then Exit Sub

ws.Cells.ClearContents 'Clear existing data from Target Worksheet
Open CSVName For Input As #1
rw = 1

Do Until EOF(1)
    Line Input #1, MyLine
    LineItems = Split(MyLine, ",")
    For c = 0 To UBound(LineItems)
        ws.Cells(rw, c + 1) = LineItems(c)
    Next c
    rw = rw + 1
Loop

Close #1

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
MsgBox rw & " Row(s) Imported", vbInformation

End Sub



This is not a robust way to import a CSV - how does it deal with a line like field1,"field2,here", field3 for example?

In addition to what Tim said, what if a quoted field includes a line break.  Bottom line, parsing data, especially human entered data, is hard
